# Appium - open in browser

Tags: android, selenium, appium, emulation, open-with

Testing mobile application using appium. When I run to test, my application opens, I can do some action, and then when I login, app takes me to browser to login to the cloud which is OK, but my problem is in the emulator. I have a question that pops-up, Open with Chrome or other app (JUST ONCE / ALWAYS). How can I avoid this dialog?

added below code but this does not help

```
caps.setCapability("appPackage", "com.android.browser");
```

I expect that when app switch me to browser then I can paste my credentials and switch back to my application and I can continue my testing

Comment: using emulator or mobile device ?

Comment: I am using emulator

Comment: so you can't avoid it. You should figure out a way around. i would suggest you to to click that button also and move forward

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I experienced similar popups too when testing apps with Appium. The only solution that works for me is extracting the xpath ([UIAutomatorViewer](https://www.guru99.com/uiautomatorviewer-tutorial.html)) and perform a click on the popup. There must be a OK or cancel button somewhere. (I do this for app crash popups, chrome privacy stuff, ...)

I perform something like:

```
if(element.isDisplayed()){
    element.click();
}
//proceed with your test
```

It is not optimal but it works. Remember if you would test this app manually you would also have to click the popup away, so I think this is OK.

Comment: Thank you, your solution works for me. I just click button

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger [KeyEvent](https://appiumpro.com/editions/34) to put apps in the background and see the home screen. Then you search for browser icon and click it. Once in browser, you can use the [context commands](http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/context/set-context/) to automate the webview.

After you done with browser, you can [resume](http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/device/app/launch-app/) the native app.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes there are some testing that makes us out of the application, `Appium` provides features for us to switch to the application we want. Please try this method :

```
driver.startActivity(new Activity("com.example", "ActivityName"));
```

You must know the name of your application bundle and its main activity.
You can read the documentation [here](http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/device/activity/start-activity/).